# How to change input box icon height to center?

Tags: css

I have a login form on my website which could have been improved when it comes to keeping the input if it fails (username or email already exists). I came to think about some old registration forms that I'd seen a few months ago. I started working on some input boxes with color (border and icon background) and icons to change if the username or email exist, don't exist or while its searching.

I have some problems with icon alignment i want to move the icon box all the way to the right without using `margin-right:-9px;`, I'm also gone be using font awesome icons instead of "X" but that shouldn't prove difficult if i get some help with the alignment.

Could someone please have a look at the example and try to change the icon and icon background alignment?

http://codepen.io/AvatarRazor/pen/Eybqkp?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your work easier, I just added `padding: 10px` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.usericonbox`.

```css
body {font:10px verdana; color:#777f8c; cursor:default; background-color:#232428;}
body,html{min-width:780px; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; font:13px "open sans",sans-serif;}
span {color: #05c7f7}



.inputs {
    position: relative;
 width:280px;
}
.usericonbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
 margin-right:-9px;
    background-color: #2af;
 color:#fff !important;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.inputs input {
 background-color:#0d0f11;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 height:32px;
 padding-left:7px;
    border:1px solid black;
 outline: none;
 color:#05c7f7
}



.inputs input:active {
 border:1px solid #2af;
}

.inputs input:focus {
 border:1px solid #2af;
}
```

```html
<center style="margin-top:20px;"> 
 
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <span class="usericonbox">X</span>
</div>
 
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want to use `margin:-9px;`, I tried to change other element's CSS:

```
.inputs {
    position: relative;
    width:280px;
    padding:0px 10px; //Added this line
}
```